# How to change photo screen saver slide show speed from registery or commandline in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, windows-registry

In Windows 10 , 
How to change photo screen saver slide show **speed** from **registery** or through **commandline** in Windows 10  to "slow" speed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily find out those values yourself using Sysinternals process Monitor. In the end you will see these values:

```
Key   : HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows Photo Viewer\Slideshow\Screensaver
Value : Speed (DWORD) 
Values: 0-2 (slow-fast)
```

Comment: Great , Thank you very much :)